# How to retrieve overlap record by dates

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I have these tables

`employee(id, name)`

`employeekey(id, employeeid, keyid, startdate, enddate)`

`key(id, code)`

I have records that overlap by dates in employeekey

```
id   employeeid   keyid   startdate   enddate
1    emp1         k001    01/01/2016  NULL
2    emp1         k002    02/06/2016  03/07/2016
3    emp2         k003    01/06/2016  30/06/2016
4    emp2         k003    01/07/2016  15/07/2016
5    emp3         k004    01/05/2016  15/05/2016
6    emp3         k005    10/05/2016  15/05/2016
```

The emp1 and emp3 overlap in dates of keys assignments I want a query to return that. This was my progress but I get all employees who have 2 or more keys even if they don't overlap in dates as in the results above. I want only those who overlap as seen below.

```
id   employeeid   keyid   startdate   enddate
1    emp1         k001    01/01/2016  NULL
2    emp1         k002    02/06/2016  03/07/2016
5    emp3         k004    01/05/2016  15/05/2016
6    emp3         k005    10/05/2016  15/05/2016
```

Progress

```
select e.id as employeeid, e.name, k.id as keyid, ek.startdate, ek.enddate
from employee e 
inner join employeekey ek on ek.employeeid = e.id 
inner join key k on k.id = ek.keyid
where exists 
(
    select count(1), e2.id, e2.name
    from employee e2
    inner join employeekey2 ek2 on ek2.employeeid = e2.id
    where e.id = e2.id 
    group by e2.id, e2.name
    having count(e2.id) > 1
)
order by 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a query like this:

```
;with overlaps as (
select *
from employeekey ek
where exists (
    select 1
    from employeekey eki
    where ek.id <> eki.id
      and ek.employeeid = eki.employeeid
      -- I use `<=` and `>=` instead of `between` because of date comparing problems with it 
      and ek.startdate >= eki.startdate
      and ek.startdate <= coalesce(eki.enddate, getdate())
    )
)
select *
from employeekey ek
where ek.employeeid in (
    select employeeid
    from overlaps
    );
```

[**SQL Server Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3ab357/1)

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO:](http://rextester.com/FCBD38328)

```
SELECT A.ID, B.*
FROM employeeKey A
LEFT JOIN employeeKey  B
  on A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
 and (B.StartDate between A.StartDate and Coalesce(A.EndDate,GetDate()) OR
      B.EndDate between A.StartDate and Coalesce(A.EndDate,GetDate()))
 and A.KeyID < B.KeyID
 Where B.ID is not null;
```

Giving us:  Note that both ID's are represented here as is the overlapping 2nd+ record

```
+----+----+----+------------+-------+------------+------------+
|    | ID | id | employeeid | keyid | startdate  |  enddate   |
+----+----+----+------------+-------+------------+------------+
|  1 |  1 |  2 | emp1       | k002  | 2016/06/02 | 2016/07/03 |
|  2 |  5 |  6 | emp3       | k005  | 2016/05/10 | 2016/05/15 |
+----+----+----+------------+-------+------------+------------+
```

We could get both overlapping records back this way.

```
--Optional to just use A.ID and B.* to see all the IDs
--Select a.ID, B.*
SELECT B.*
FROM employeeKey A
LEFT JOIN employeeKey  B
  on A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
 and (B.StartDate between A.StartDate and Coalesce(A.EndDate,GetDate()) OR
      B.EndDate between A.StartDate and Coalesce(A.EndDate,GetDate()))
 and A.KeyID < B.KeyID
 Where B.ID is not null

--You could exclude the union and add the optional select.
UNION ALL
SELECT A.*
FROM employeeKey A
LEFT JOIN employeeKey  B
  on A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID
 and (B.StartDate between A.StartDate and Coalesce(A.EndDate,GetDate()) OR
      B.EndDate between A.StartDate and Coalesce(A.EndDate,GetDate()))
 and A.KeyID < B.KeyID
 Where B.ID is not null
 Order by EmployeeID, KeyID
 ;
```

Giving us:

```
+----+----+------------+-------+------------+------------+
|    | id | employeeid | keyid | startdate  |  enddate   |
+----+----+------------+-------+------------+------------+
|  1 |  1 | emp1       | k001  | 2016/01/01 | NULL       |
|  2 |  2 | emp1       | k002  | 2016/06/02 | 2016/07/03 |
|  3 |  5 | emp3       | k004  | 2016/05/01 | 2016/05/15 |
|  4 |  6 | emp3       | k005  | 2016/05/10 | 2016/05/15 |
+----+----+------------+-------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I want the second resultset output from my question. What I am getting right now is the first resultset. So you got those who overlap emp1 and emp3 but I want to list also all the keys assigned. On this case I cannot see k001 and k004

Comment: 1 and 4 are there if we return all of a.* and b.*  you'll note that the ID's of both records are present in the first approach.   Or we can union the two results as in my update.

Comment: Awesome, Thanks!

Comment: @MaximusDecimus may want to look at shA.t's reponse.  Cleaner seems to work as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would try `EXISTS`

```
select id, employeeid, keyid, startdate, enddate
from employeekey ek1
where exists 
(
    select 1
    from employeekey ek2
    where ek1.id != ek2.id and
          ek1.employeeid = ek2.employeeid and
          ek2.startdate < Coalesce(ek1.enddate,GetDate()) and
          Coalesce(ek2.EndDate,GetDate()) > ek1.startdate   
)
```

Comment: Note quite right.  Returns all 6 records. http://rextester.com/EYBX22604